# Generic extension for EF entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, extension-methods

**Task:** write a generic extension for Entity Framework entities

I am not sure if this is even possible due to the fact that each entity usually will have differing properties, but I have a group of entities that share a few common properties and all I was wondering if it is even possible to build a generic extension instead of always having to write out the same code for each entity.

I spent a bit of time researching this, but there is not much , which leads me to believe this just is not possible.

Anyway, contrary to my better judgment I am going to ask a stupid question on StackOverFlow.

This is what I was thinking, but obviously a non compile-able example, but at least you will get the idea.

```
public static List<TEntity> Generic<TEntity>(this DbContext db, string name)
{
    return db.TEntity.Where(s => s.Name == name);
}
```

I poke in the right direction would be appreciated.

And just for clarity, I have never spent a single hour in a classroom for programming, I am self taught, so if it is not possible to this, could the answer explain please explain technically why this is not possible in Entity Framework. As I could not find anything substantial myself.

Comment: *I have a group of entities that share a few common properties and all I was wondering if it is even possible to build a generic extension*, first thing to do, have the classes extend a common interface that denotes the field you want to access. then you can make `public static IQueryable<MyInterface> SomeAwesomeFiltering(this IQueryable<MyInterface> myAwesomeList, string name){ return myAwesomeList.Where(x => x.CommonProperty == name); }` -- notice the `this` for extensions.

Comment: @BagusTesa Brilliant, that would work well. Thanks!!!

Comment: @KyloRen could you give an example (in your question) on how you expect to use this?

Comment: @JensKloster, Bagus Tesa has solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Bagus Tesa, I was able to solve this.

As Bagus tesa states, make an `interface` that references the common properties of the `Entities` and refference the `interface` with the `Entities` and make an extension that way.

The code I used,

```
public static IQueryable<IFilterEntity> FilterEntity(this BaseViewModel vm,
 IQueryable<IFilterEntity> list)
{
    return list.Where(s => s.Name == vm.name && 
                           s.DateMonth == vm.Month &&
                           s.DateYear == vm.Year);
}
```

The interface,

```
public interface IFilterEntity
{
    string Name { get; set; } 

    int? DateYear { get; set; }

    int? DateMonth { get; set; }
}
```

The BaseViewModel,

```
public class BaseViewModel
{      
    string Name => RootVm.Name;

    int? DateYear => RootVm.SelectedDate.Month;

    int? DateMonth => RootVm.SelectedDate.Month;
}
```

Thanks for all the help with. And I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> Filter(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null)
            {
db.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking().AsQueryable().Where(filter);}
```